# URL Masking Using httpd

Tags: linux, apache, admin, httpd.conf, devops

I need to write a rule for url masking in httpd even if the target url keep on changing. example
My request url should always be static like:
**http://request.com/** and target should first go to the **http://target.com/login.html** and also after the login target url will change like  **http://target.com/myaccount** but on browser it should be always 
**http://request.com/**.

i.e. for any of the url change in the target host the primary should always be static.
like :- **http://request.com/**  -->  **http://target.com/***

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, or at least with the data you provide.

How can you have the same URL always if the backend destination changes, how are you going to calculate which destination to deliver the request.

Comment: That will be managed by my application i.e. session management.

Comment: On the first hit, it will go to the login based on session, after successful login it will go to the desired file or pages.

Comment: sounds like a bad idea, but if your application will do and you are fine with it, the answer still applies, Apache can't do that.